# Intersecting Polygon by a Gridded Polygon returns unexpected result

Tags: qgis, postgis, splitting, st-split

I have a regular polygon grid (`grid`) and irregular polygons (`block`). You can download the data here: https://we.tl/t-BczpR2K2lw

[image: Raster and Polygon]

I want to intersect the orange polygons (`block`) by the regular polygon grid (`grid`).
`grid` is of type `POLYGON`, while `block` is of type `MULTIPOLYGON`. In the result of the split I expect to have as many split polygons, as there are "rastercells".
There are 416 rows in `grid` and 8 rows in `block`.

So far I have tried

```
CREATE TABLE foo AS
    SELECT ST_Intersection(block.geom, grid.geom)
    FROM block, grid;
```

This results in 3328 rows (which is 416 * 8). When I try to visualize this in QGIS, I do not get the icon for a `vector layer`, but for an `image`.

Why do I get 3328 rows as a result? This should be less then 416...

Comment: Nice. I belive each block is being split by each grid cell. So one block with 10 cells will be split 10 times. I dont know how to prevent it though

Comment: Must it be done using PostGIS? The tool *Intersection* in QGIS will give your desired result (assuming the grid is polygon).

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/vp0VGc9

Comment: The QGIS tool *Intersection*, as I mentioned previously.

Comment: In postgis, it still leaves me with 3328 rows though... This is something, I cannot get my head around why this happens!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your are doing a cross join between the two layers, computing an intersection between each cell and each polygon, even if they are disjoint. Most "intersection" will be null/empty.

Try to restrict the computation only where the geometries intersect each others:

```sql
CREATE TABLE foo AS
    SELECT ST_Intersection(block.geom, grid.geom)
    FROM block 
    JOIN grid
      ON ST_Intersects(block.geom, grid.geom);
```

Comment: That easy... JGH, this is something that happens every now and then to me. I do a cross join (in these spatial operations) without being aware that I am doing a cross join. Is there a rule of thumb to realize, that I am doing a cross join?

Comment: @Stophface When you write two table name in the `FROM`, without a `WHERE` that effectively joins the tables, it is a cross join. The easiest is to systematically write a `JOIN + ON` when several tables are involved

Comment: Thanks mate, that helps!